# How to implement subtype functionality in Oracle Spatial?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I am planning to shift my entire database from arcgis to oracle.
I will not be using ArcSDE services also. 
I need subtitutes for ESRI's functionalities like domain, subtype, relationships in oracle.
I have some how worked out two them i.e. domains and relationships, but no alternatives for subtypes have striked me.

Comment: Using ArcGIS directly with Oracle Spatial will be troublesome, you would be advised to use the ArcSDE Gateway with E$RI products.

Comment: thanks for your help...but my question was that can i implement subtypes in oracle. I dont want to use ArcGIS or any ESRI products. Does oracle spatial 11g provide such kind of functionality?

Comment: I would look at using insert triggers, or implement it at the application level.